# How to license number of users at the database?

Tags: delphi, licensing, interbase

Given a Delphi and Interbase client-server application, I'd like to license the application by the number of users at the database. How can this be done with commercial licensing software? I don't see any of those listing features that look like they would cover this. Every user initially logs on to the database. The database seems so available that it would be open to any user - or at least administrators. Would I have to also write a Delphi exe or dll to run on the server - perhaps as a function in the database - with the licensing connected to that? Not sure how to proceed.
BTW, Interbase licenses simultaneous users, but I think they wrote that right into the server, but I want something similar.

Answer (score 1):

To control simultaneous client connections you definitively need a server side application.
It can be a simple tcp/ip socket server as a service (daemon on linux) or another (midas?) server layer.

When your client app starts it call a server method for example Session.Connect, here you count active connections and return false (no code) in case of maximum limit reaches.
When application closes you notify server with Session.Disconnect. to decrease connection count.

Also is a good idea to keep a live (permanent) connection between client app and server service (as I sad sockets) to handle application hangups, uncontrolled restarts and process this event for example OnSockedDisconnect on server side, to decrease connection count and handle for disconnect propery, for example write in logs etc...

Of course communication should be crypted (handshaked), to avoid unwanted guests.
You can play also with sim cardreaders etc..

This method will not provide a industrial (nuclear) level of security, but if coded corectly it can take some time even for an expert hacker to broke it.

OR, you may take a look at some ready protection tools like SafeNet (HASP protection).

Also, Firebird (and maybe Interbase) have on DB Connect / Disconnect triggers, where if user have privileges it can read connection count. But these can be easily changed if DB are stored on customer server.

Comment: Are you aware of any commercial licensing software that does this, or must one create this capability by developing something custom?

Comment: I know some software companies that uses hardware (hasp) protection. Idea with socket server it's relatively easy to implement.